# How do I get a row with a particular date in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

So right now I'm using this query:

```
select * from items where mydate = "2009-11-28"
```

and since my date is stored as a text in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, this should by all means return the one row with matching date, right? If not, what am I doing wrong?

I tried doing this:

```
select * from items where releasedate between date("2009-11-28") and date("2009-11-29")
```

and it worked fine, but always having to use between just for one day doesnt seem right.

So the second query works fine, but the first doesnt. Is there a reason? I also tried putting the date in `date()`, but that didnt work either.

Comment: Why did you use 'between' in your query here?first query didn't work in your case or what?

Comment: Yeah, the first query doesnt return my row. And I do have a row with that date.

Comment: Are you sure you have the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format and not in `yyyy-mm-dd H:is` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this query,

```
select * from items where mydate like '2009-11-28%'
```

Comment: if your db contains date as '2009-11-28 04:40' when you using like '2009-11-28%' it will ignores other chars (i mean after that '8' char will be ignored'

Answer (score 1):

What does your insert statement look like, and what does the table definition look like?  I would bet you need to convert the date from the first query string with the 'date' function instead of doing a raw string.

Also, if you're converting real dates, make sure its exactly "2009-11-28".  If you do a general date argument, you probably aren't exactly at midnight, and a range would be a valid way to query rather than a fixed date value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from items where mydate = "2009-11-28"  // Here do not use double quotation
```

instead, try this

```
select * from items where mydate = '2009-11-28'
```